# If (item1,item2) in A or B or C

Tags: python, arrays, logic

Can't find any similar questions online, would appreciate the help.
I would like to find out if two values appear in any lists. For example, I have

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 4]
B = [5, 7, 9, 0]
C = [2, 7, 3, 9]
```

Are there any quick methods to check if `[1, 2]` is present anywhere in order (consecutively) in the lists?

Furthermore, is there a way to check which list it appears in?
e.g. for [7,3] it'd return C

Comment: In order, consecutively?  So, [1,2,5,8] would be a match, but [1,3,2,9] would not?  There's no single method for that, but it's a simple loop.

Comment: so your desired result is simply `False`  as the sequence 1,2 does not occur in any of the lists A,B,C ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
any([(1, 2) in zip(lst, lst[1:]) for lst in [A, B, C]])
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! Did not understand how it works at first but learnt a lot after some digging on the internet (qwq) ure a life saver<3

Comment: Furthermore, is there a way to check which list it appears in?

Comment: `[i for i,lst in enumerate([A,B,C]) if (1,2) in zip(lst,lst[1:])]`

Answer (score 1):

Python offers an easy way to check if an element is part of a list:

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 4]
B = [5, 7, 9, 0]
C = [2, 7, 3, 9]

values = [1, 2]
for v in values:
    if (v in A):
        print("A has {}".format(v))
    if (v in B):
        print("B has {}".format(v))
    if (v in C):
        print("C has {}".format(v))
```

Comment: thanks for taking ur time in answering my question! However I'm looking for something that could check whether the numbers are present consecutively and not seperately in different lists. But I appreciate your help!